# How can I allow access to Jupyter Notebook running in browser on AWS EC2 to only a single IP address?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook, acl, amazon-acl

I'm trying to allow only a single IP Address to access my jupyter notebook which is running in a browser on an ec2 instance.

I tried to set the inbound rules in my acl to allow all traffic from only my IP Address. Furthermore, I tried to do it with a security group. Which would be the more suitable option?

My final target is to grant access to a limited number of users from one of our smaller locations based on their IP addresses.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: please provide more inputs like Subnet, ELB or single EC2 instance, internet gateway, port etc. also would be useful to share the screenshot of Ping and telnet

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is that it depends both on what your other infrastructure looks like, whether the additional users are given console/resource access privileges via IAM, how comfortable you are with the various security settings available, and how much time you're looking to spend managing access privileges.

The following table, [pulled from the AWS VPC Security Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Security.html), offers a direct comparison between the features of the two options you asked about, Security Groups and Network ACLs.

[image: VPC Security: Security Group vs Network ACL]

Using either a security group or network ACL will work, but I'd recommend using a **security group** because it sounds like your use-case is allowing access control on a resource-by-resource (instance level) basis, rather than a subnet level basis.

[From the docs,](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html) to whitelist IP addresses for a security group, you'll need to add a rule to the security group that you have attached to the EC2 instance (or create and attach a new one):

> **To add a rule to a security group for inbound SSH traffic over IPv4 (console)**
>
> 1. In the navigation pane of the Amazon EC2 console, choose Instances. Select your instance and look at the Description tab; Security groups
>      lists the security groups that are associated with the instance.
>      Choose view inbound rules to display a list of the rules that are in
>      effect for the instance.
> 2. In the navigation pane, choose Security Groups. Select one of the security groups associated with your instance.
> 3. In the details pane, on the Inbound tab, choose Edit. In the dialog, choose Add Rule, and then choose SSH from the Type list.
> 4. In the Source field, choose My IP to automatically populate the field with the public IPv4 address of your local computer.
>      Alternatively, choose Custom and specify the public IPv4 address of
>      your computer or network in CIDR notation. For example, if your IPv4
>      address is 203.0.113.25, specify 203.0.113.25/32 to list this single
>      IPv4 address in CIDR notation. If your company allocates addresses
>      from a range, specify the entire range, such as 203.0.113.0/24.
>
> For information about finding your IP address, see Before You Start.
>
> 5. Choose Save.

Lastly, if the sole purpose of your EC2 instance is to run a Jupyter Notebook, I suggest checking out [SageMaker hosted Jupyter Notebooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/nbi.html), as they may be more convenient for what you're trying to do (easily access a cloud hosted Jupyter notebook, but without needing to SSH in from a terminal).